# Error in programmatically creating FileAppender using log4j2 . Giving NULLPointer exception

Tags: java, log4j2

When i run the application log4j2 gives below exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: name
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender.<init>(AbstractAppender.java:211)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.<init>(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:138)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender.<init>(FileAppender.java:259)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender.<init>(FileAppender.java:42)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:104)
```

My Log4j2 Properties

```
logger.test.name = test
logger.test.level = INFO
logger.test.appenderRef.$1.ref = test
logger.test.additivity = false
appender.test.type = File
appender.test.name = test
appender.test.fileName = ssp1.log
appender.test.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.test.layout.pattern = %-5p %d - %m%n
```

and my Java code is

```
a = FileAppender.newBuilder().withFileName(m_basedir + File.separator + "logs" + File.separator + stamp + ".log").withAppend(false).setName(log.getName()).build();
a.start();
```

Comment: Check if `log.getName()` does not return `null`.

Comment: No.. It is returning some value .. Even i hadrcoded the value and checkd it.. just to ensure. But still it is throwing the same error